# CMD Batch File Missing Operator Error

Tags: batch-file

Getting a 'missing operator' error on line 3 when executing the following in a DOS batch file - so the second variable ends up as zero - why is this so?

```
SET VAR1=0.3
ECHO %VAR1%
SET /A VAR2=2*%VAR1%
ECHO %VAR2%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because `set /a` can work with integers only. It's the dot, that ruins your Syntax.

As a Workaround, you can use (with "big" numbers):

```
SET VAR1=3/10
ECHO %VAR1%
SET /A VAR2=200*%VAR1%
ECHO %VAR2%
```

That does `set /a VAR2=200*3/10`

Note: as `set /a` calculates with integers only, `2*0.3` = `2*3/10` = `0.6` gives you `0` only (no rounding, just cutting)

Comment: The interim multiplication with `10` is a nice work-around to do simple floating-point-like calculations; to round the result correctly, you could add `5` just before dividing by `10`...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Floating point number in BAT you can use mixed script  BAT/VBS,BAT/JS or BAT/PS.

Here an example with a BAT/VBS code :

```
@echo off   

::Creating the Math VBS file

 if not exist "Math.vbs" echo Wscript.echo replace(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)),",",".")>Math.vbs


SET VAR1=0.3

::Calling the Math VBS
call:Math 2 * %var1%
echo Result : %Result%

::Calling the Math VBS
Call:Math Cos(2000*%Result%)
echo Result : %Result%


exit/b

:Math
echo Working : "%*"
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo Math.vbs "%*"') do set "Result=%%a"
```

**Output :**

> Working : "2 * 0.3"
>
> Result : 0.6
>
> Working : "Cos(2000*0.6)"
>
> Result : 0.996095822518803

Like you see you also can use the standard Math function of VBS (Cos,Sin,Hex,Rnd,Int,Fix,Log,Oct,SGn,Sqr,Abs).

Comment: I like that it uses a working math parser/engine. I would like this better if it didn't have to create a separate script that does all the work (and if there were some way for it to clean up after itself—which I don't think is cleanly possible if multiple scripts "do math" at once.)

Comment: Sure it's possible juste put a `del math.vbs 2>nul` before the `exit/b`

Comment: And if multiple scripts are doing math at roughly the same time, and one deletes the script before the other begins using it (but after it's checked for the existence of the script)? It's a small problem, but a problem nonetheless. You could randomize the name of the file to reduce the chances of collision, but it still seems like a limitation to be avoided. If you ran hundreds of math-aware scripts simultaneously, the chances of failure could become significant.

Comment: It should be tested for sure !

Answer (score 1):

Multiply your nonintegral numbers with a power of 10, say 100, and calculate with integers. If you end up with say 314 in the var x you finally do:

```
echo %x:~0,-2%.%x:~-2%
```

and you get 3.14

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the intelligent solution provided by @SachaDee would be to use PowerShell, which allows passing code via the command-line.

PowerShell's syntax for the other math functions is a little verbose, but it does have the advantage of not needing to create temp files. On the down side, it's probably at least a little slower that invoking VBScript.

```
@SETLOCAL
@ECHO OFF

CALL :EVAL RESULT1 "1.5 * 3.1415926"
@ECHO Result: %RESULT1%

CALL :EVAL COS_60deg "[Math]::Cos(3.1415926/3)"
@ECHO Result: %COS_60deg%

CALL :EVAL RESULT1 "[Math]::Pow(.25,3)"
@ECHO Result: %RESULT1%

EXIT /B

:EVAL
FOR /F %%r IN ('PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "%~2" ^<NUL') DO (SET "%~1=%%~r")
EXIT /B
```

The best practical solution is probably either not to do this at all in CMD/batch (my preference) or to scale the decimal values by powers of 10 (also a solution) so that you're always doing integer arithmetic, then "scale" it back (using substring operations).