# How to have a double in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to make a batch file that will have doubles instead of just integers. Maybe I am looking it up wrong or maybe it is just not possible but I could not find anything on this.

Here is what I tried to test it

```
@echo off
set /a test=1.5
echo %test%
set /a test=%test%+%test%
echo %test%
pause >nul
```

When I run this here is what I get:

```
Missing operator.
1
2
```

What I was expecting was 1.5 and then 3. By "Missing operator" I am presuming there is something I should do rather than `/a` but I don't know what it is.

Comment: you can do it with the additional [jeval.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6212) by dbenham.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34588423/2152082)

Comment: Thanks for showing me the duplicate; that really sucks for what I was trying to do that /a is ints only but I think I can use that work around thats posted there.

Comment: yes, it sucks. But SachaDee's answer there shows a fine way to work around it. Also mojo's answer with powershell works fine, but VBS is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch maths in integer-only. `set` is expecting to perform a calculation, but since you can only use integers, it's objecting to `.` where it expects an operator, hence 'missing operator'